# Remove extra spaces in ASP.NET HTML page title?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a problem.

I assign title value of page using VB.NET as `page.title = "a"` but when I run the page and look in page view source i found it shows like `<title>   a   </title>`

Problem is that i want to remove all the spaces between title tag and it show like this `<title>a</title>`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I *believe* that per normal HTML rules the extra white-space at the ends *is effectively ignored* and should not show up at all -- thus both versions shown should be the same when rendered. Does the title text look odd? (Shifted right from other titles)

Comment: it shows odd and how i shifted it to right

Comment: @pst: That's quite not correct. HTML will render single spaces as defined in the source, but any additional whitespace past this is ignored. This is as per the HTML specification: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/text.html#h-9.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know this is just a quirk (bug?) with ASP.NET rendering.

I came across this myself a while back, and found this fix here: [Weird white space in title tag](http://forums.asp.net/t/1392181.aspx). If it bothers you then just stick this in you page code to fix it:

```
Protected Overrides Sub Render(ByVal writer As System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter)

    Dim stringWriter As New System.IO.StringWriter()
    Dim htmlWriter As New HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter)
    MyBase.Render(htmlWriter)
    Dim html As String = stringWriter.ToString()
    Dim t1 As Integer = html.IndexOf("<title>")
    Dim t2 As Integer = html.IndexOf("</title>") + 8
    Dim newTitleTag As String = html.Substring(t1, t2 - t1)
    html = html.Replace(newTitleTag, String.Format("<title>{0}</title>", Me.Title))

    writer.Write(html)

End Sub
```

Comment: The linked page also shows the C# translation, in case anyone was looking for that instead (like me!)